# Error:An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x19) was found in the element content of the document

Tags: java, unicode

r:An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x19) was found in the element content of the document.

I've already \ all the ' in the document, not sure what other characters are causing this error

```
<string-array name="J2d">
     <item>D.   the  need  for adaptive   equipment   and  assistance  from   others.</item>
      <item> D.    limited</item>
      <item>D.    fatigue and endurance  levels.</item>
         <item>D.    Explain    to   the  child  that   he  will miss  recess due   to  the   inability   to cooperate  with  therapy.</item>
             <item>D. Hand the individual a key to place in a lock</item>
             <item> D.  clawing.</item>
             <item>D.   ataxia. </item>
             <item>D.    unilateral      neglect.</item>
             <item>D.    Muscle    length  control  via finger to nose     tests</item>
             <item>D.   observe     the   child   entering  the  clinic  and  taking   off his  coat and  shoes.</item>
                 <item>D.   calculate     maximum   age adjusted    heart  rate (MAHR).</item>
                    <item>D.    Assess     the    individual\'s      topographical    orientation  skills.</item>
                    <item>D.   endurance.</item>
                    <item>D.  Standardized   test</item>
                    <item>D.   early morning   and  again in  the  afternoon.</item>
                    <item>D.   protective  extension  response</item>
                    <item>D.   request   information    from the  referring physician.  </item>
                    <item>D     psychoeducational session</item>
                    <item>D. maximal assistance</item>
                    <item>D. administering functional performance tests </item>
                    <item>D.  determine    the  social   environment of  the individual.</item>
                    <item>D. unilateral precedes bilateral in typical development</item>
                    <item>D. bitemporal hemianopia</item>
                    <item>D. attempt to force the individuals arm into flexion</item>
                    <item>D. The client is able to learn academic skills from 3rd grade to 7th grade level</item>
                    <item>D.    figure ground  discrimination.</item>
                    <item>D.    fine  motor   skills.</item>
                    <item>D.   Leisure     interests</item>
                    <item>D.   interest   in  and   ability  to  perform   multiple roles.</item>
                    <item>D.   Observation of the child experiencing difficulties while riding his bike outside</item>



 </string-array>
            </resources>
```

Comment: @tsnorri: It is likely a duplicate, but no answer has been selected.

Comment: ASCII control codes like 0x19 cannot be included in an XML 1.0 document at all. (They can be included in an XML 1.1 document escaped as `&#x19;` but it's probably a bad idea to rely on this as not much supports it.) You should remove control codes from strings before including them in XML. Do not add any backslashes, XML doesn't have any escaping scheme involving backslashes.

Comment: ok i have to admit i tried reading up on unicode and xml protocol but it was all too much. what i did try though was just getting rid of all the spaces at the end of each < /item>  and it worked. thanks guys!

Comment: 0x19 is a smart single quote. You often find this in document produced by Microsoft Office products: `individual’s` (Unicode 0x19) vs `individual's`